#  how to map Json data into java beans?

Tags: java, android, json, javabeans

i have some JSON data from server and i want to make java beans out of it.
can anybody help?

```
"recent_data":{[            
                            "data_number":<data NUMBER>,
                             "bill_number":"<BILLING  NUMBER>"
                             "data_date":"<data DATE>",
                             "due_date":"<DUE DATE>",

                           "data_amount":{ 
                           "amount_exchanged":"<AMOUNT EXCHANGED>"
                           "amount_deducted":"<AMOUNT  DEDUCTED>",
                            "amount":"<AMOUNT>"
                            },
                           "total_amount":"TOTAL AMOUNT>",
                           "total_discounts":"<TOTAL_ DISCOUNTS>",
                            "adjusted_amount":"<ADJUSTED AMOUNT>",
                            "data_type":"Normal",
                            "data_status":"Open"
                 ]}
```

Comment: that does not look like valid json btw. arrays can not contain properties as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29%20JSONObject) to parse your json string and to populate java beans if you want that (or you could work directly with JSONObject.

It is a bit verbose, but it's built in in android.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), it works better than JSONObject library.